# When the page scrolls, the CSS top margin is fixed

Tags: css

I have two div.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="top_bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="mb">Call Us: (+92) 42 3578 1448-9 - Mail: info@mymail.com</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="social_icons">
        <a href="#">FB.icon</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second div

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        my navigation bar
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the second div position top to become zero and fixed when the page scrolls down. How do you do it?

Comment: You have to use jquery scroll top function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/Lsr2yfjj/)**

**CSS:**

```
.sticky{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
            $('.navbar-header').addClass("sticky");
        }
        else{
            $('.navbar-header').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have changed `top_bar` into the same container of `navbar-header` and used Jquery `.scroll()` method to fix the `top_bar` on scroll. Hope this will helps.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        my navigation bar
    </div>
     <div id="top_bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="mb">Call Us: (+92) 42 3578 1448-9 - Mail: info@mymail.com</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="social_icons">
        <a href="#">FB.icon</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.navbar-header{
    background: #ccc
}
#top_bar{

        background: #0390d4
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  width: 100%; }
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('#top_bar'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 100) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tvshajeer/ao7gs1cd/)

Comment: :) Accept it as answer If you find it helpful.@saeed ahmed

Answer (score 1):

Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/3ohdxt21/1/)

Here is the jQuery code is---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 60) {
            jQuery(".myDiv").addClass("fixed_div"); 
        }               
        if (scroll <= 60) {
            jQuery(".myDiv").removeClass("fixed_div"); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the CSS Code is---

```
.myDiv{
        background:red;
        height:50px;
        transition:all .25s;
    }
    .fixed_div{
        position:fixed;
        left:10px;
        right:10px;
        top:10px;
        background:blue;
    }
```

Here is the HTML code is---

```
    <h1>Scroll down to see the effect</h1>
    <div class="myDiv">
        Scroll Down 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS way:

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let topBar = document.querySelector('#top_bar');
  let header = document.querySelector('.navbar-header');

  if (window.scrollY >= topBar.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
    header.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
});
```